# How to read the buffer info from a camera?

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qr-code

I have one particular part of a Qt application that is supposed to take a photo from a camera and decode a QR code using the qzxing library. However, I cannot get the photo out of the buffer! I know the decoding is working well, because if I save the photo to a file and then immediately reload it as a QImage, everything works (except, of course, that the program doesn't block until the image is fully saved, so it'll try to decode a half-image, then on the second attempt, decode the first image.)!

There are plenty of people out there asking this question, but nobody seems to have a COMPLETE answer.  I've been researching and guessing-and-testing for the last six hours. Qt documentation for QCameraImageCapture exists, but doesn't talk about passing the buffer or casting in QImage at all. There are a few answers on SO that have a couple of guesses at casting the image into a QImage, and a couple more that talk about finding the buffer, but nobody has a complete answer. The Qt example documentation isn't even complete, and their example project (broken links abound throughout the web) doesn't discuss what it is doing.

Here's a sample of some test code that runs and compiles using a mainwindow.ui with a pushbutton called "pushButton" and a vertical layout called "verticalLayout."  What am I doing wrong?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QCameraImageCapture>
#include <qzxing/QZXing.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void cameraReceiver(int f,QVideoFrame u);
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QCameraViewfinder   *viewfinder;
    QCamera             *invCam;
    QCameraImageCapture *rawImage;
    QZXing              *decoder;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //build camera
    QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras) {
        if (cameraInfo.deviceName() == "/dev/video0")
            invCam = new QCamera(cameraInfo);

    }

    //build decoder
    decoder = new QZXing;
    decoder->setDecoder(QZXing::DecoderFormat_QR_CODE);

    //build viewfinder and link to camera
    viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
    viewfinder->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(viewfinder);
    invCam->setViewfinder(viewfinder);

    //build image buffer, set camera mode to capture
    rawImage = new QCameraImageCapture(invCam);
    invCam->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
    invCam->start();
    viewfinder->show();

    connect(rawImage,SIGNAL(imageAvailable(int,QVideoFrame)),this,SLOT(cameraReceiver(int,QVideoFrame)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::cameraReceiver(int f,QVideoFrame u) {

    QImage currentImage(u.bits(), u.width(), u.height(), u.bytesPerLine(), QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(u.pixelFormat()));
    QString output = decoder->decodeImage(currentImage);
    qDebug() << output;

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    rawImage->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer);
    rawImage->capture();
}
```

EDIT: Currently on a Linux environment, camera is embedded.  The viewfinder displays just fine, and like I said, I can capture image to FILE no problem - the camera is working nicely

EDIT 2: as soon as I posted on SO I have found the answer:

The "connect" call should use the "imageCaptured" signal:

```
connect(rawImage,SIGNAL(imageCaptured(int,QImage)),this,SLOT(cameraReceiver(int,QImage)));
```

Then, the buffer has a QImage sitting right in it.

```
void MainWindow::cameraReceiver(int f,QImage u) {

    QString output = decoder->decodeImage(u);
    qDebug() << output;
}
```

Comment: How is the camera connected to the computer?

Comment: Which platform are you using, embedded?  Windows?  Linux?  Other?

Comment: What kind of camera (make and model)?  Are there specific commands that need to be sent to the camera?

Comment: Yes.  The answer to your question is: Yes, a human has made a program that successfully reads buffer info from a camera.

Comment: @DanKorn It should be more _at least a human ..._. I bet there are a lot of humans out there that succeeded in the task.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you have found a solution for yourself, but in case someone is stuck with it, here is an important hint if anyone needs to use `QVideoFrame`:

The problem is the wrong usage of `QVideoFrame`. The frame has to be mapped before you can access it:

```
void MainWindow::cameraReceiver(int f,QVideoFrame u) {
    if (u.isValid()) {
        if(u.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly)) {//map the frame
            uchar * data = new uchar[u.mappedBytes()];//copy the buffer for QImage
            memcpy(data, u.bits(), u.mappedBytes());
            QImage image(data,
                         u.width(),
                         u.height(),
                         u.bytesPerLine(),
                         QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(u.pixelFormat()),
                         simpleCleanupHandler,//handles the buffer cleanup
                         data);//required for the cleanup
            u.unmap();//unmap the frame

            QString output = decoder->decodeImage(currentImage);
            qDebug() << output;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `QImage` will not copy the buffer, you have to do it on your own. The `simpleImageCleanupHandler` looks like this:

```
static void simpleCleanupHandler(void *info)
{
    delete[] (uchar*)info;
}
```